# IndexError: list assignment index out of range

Tags: python, массивы, arraylist

Вот задача:
Даны два числа n и m. Создайте двумерный массив `A[n][m]`, заполните его таблицей умножения `A[i][j]=i*j` и выведите на экран.

Вот мой код:

```
def printer(mass):
  for i in range(len(mass)):
    print(mass[i])

n, m = map(int, input().split())
mass = [[0] for i in range(n)]
for i in range(n):
  for j in range(m):
    mass[i][j] = i * j
printer(mass)
```

Когда запускаю вылезает ошибка:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/admin1/PycharmProjects/2/homeworks/E (Состязания - 3).py", line
>   10, in 
>       mass[i][j] = i * j IndexError: list assignment index out of range

Никак не могу понять что не так...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы инициализируете только 1 элемент массива массивов. Приведу пример. Пусть n = 3:

```
[[0], [0], [0]]
```

Для того, чтобы поправить эту проблему, Вам нужно сделать следующее:

```
mass = [[0] * m for i in range(n)]
```

Тогда, если, например, m = 2, Вы получите:

```
[[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]
```

Весь код:

```
def printer(mass):
  for i in range(len(mass)):
    print(mass[i])

n, m = map(int, input().split())
mass = [[0] * m for i in range(n)]
for i in range(n):
  for j in range(m):
    mass[i][j] = i * j
printer(mass)
```

Для того, чтобы обнаруживать такие ошибки, Вы можете использовать дебаггер. Он по умолчанию встроен во все IDE. Например, в pyCharm. Вы всегда можете выполнить построчно Ваш код и посмотреть, чему равна переменная на каждой строке. В качестве примере, можете посмотреть, как устроен дебаггер на обучающем [сайте](https://pythontutor.ru/).

Если по какой-то причине, дебаггер недоступен, то Вы можете использовать `print()`. Но это менее удобно, поскольку в ряде конструкций (например, в лямбдах или скоращённой записи цикла) его использовать не получится.

Касательно кода. Будьте внимательны при испольщовании подобных конструкций:

```
[0] * 5
```

Они не производят копирование объектов. Например, попробуй выполнить следующее:

```
x = [[1]] * 5
x[0][0] = 1
print(x)
```

И посмотрите за результатом.